# High pressure Helium tanks for the Vega balloon experiments

Tags: venus, helium, venera, storage

Is there any available (scientific) information on the properties of the high pressure Helium storage tanks, used for the Vega balloon experiments on Venus?
Information on how big pressure gas they had, and their respective volume and weight.

I am writing a thesis about a possible future ballooning mission to Jupiter, but I need to know how effective the best high pressure gas storage tanks are.

Comment: The missions Vega 1 and 2 are a long time ago, there might be better high pressure Helium storage tanks now. Are there better tanks than spherical carbon fiber wound tanks?

Comment: Jupiter's atmosphere is mostly hydrogen. So the balloon should be based on mongolfiere principle, with energy source to heat the lifting gas.

Comment: The density of helium is 0.1785 and of hydrogen 0.0899 (at 273 K and 1 bar). As Heopps wrote, transporting helium to Jupiter for a balloon heavier than the surrounding gas does not make sense.

Comment: The tanks are meant for taking Hydrogen and NOT Helium to Jupiter. The atmosphere of Jupiter consists  'mostly' of Hydrogen, but is still not pure Hydrogen, but a mixture of Hydrogen and Helium, and I had calculated that it should actually be possible to fly a balloon filled with pure hydrogen in that atmosphere. But the design-stage problem is however how to transport all the hydrogen gas to Jupiter, and that's why I was asking about the Vega mission to gain some inspiration :)